# Is there a way to determine weapon strength

Tags: battlefield-3

In the description of the weapons I see range, speed and fire rates. However there has to be a difference in power.

Answer (score 4):

You're right there is a difference in power but you can't find that information in-game. There are a few damage charts around the net that give a very detailed look at each weapons damage and how effects like range and suppression change it.

**[Here](http://symthic.com/?s=bf3&sb=dmgchart)** is a *very* detailed chart and there's a simpler one **[here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/lv?key=0Ag42gMGK9WrwdHRfa0JhdW9TR1E0bjBueWVSQjc0V0E&f=true&noheader=false&gid=0)**.

At the bottom of the detailed chart it also talks about how various ammo types effect the shotguns.